# Alarm go off vs alarm goes off

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why ?:

"I came this way when I heard an alarm go off."

"I came this way when I heard an alarm goes off."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct. The reason it is "go" and not "goes" is because it is the infinitive use of the verb.

***I came this way when I heard an alarm (to) go off***.

You could also use, with little change of meaning, the present participle -

*I came this way when I heard an alarm going off*